# How to perform multiple action on multiple buttons on same form?

Tags: spring, jsp

I am displaying some data in the table and each row has two buttons. On clicking on button some data should be passed to the controller class, and the appropriate action should happen.

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/upcomingLeaves", method = RequestMethod.GET)
           public String showForm(@ModelAttribute("loginForm")EmpRegistrationForm profileForm, BindingResult result , HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model){ 


             LeaveApplyForm leaveapplyform =(LeaveApplyForm)model.get("leaveapplyform");


             try{

                    HttpSession session=super.getSession(model);
                    CommonDTOBean dtoBean=(CommonDTOBean)session.getAttribute("dtoBean");
                    List upcomingLeavesList=LeaveStatusWorker.upcomingLeaves(dtoBean);
                    session.setAttribute("upcomingLeavesList", upcomingLeavesList);
                    session.setAttribute("dtoBean", dtoBean);
                    model.addAttribute("dtoBean",dtoBean);
                    return GlobalConstants.UPCOMING_LEAVES;
                    }catch(Exception e){

                    }


             return GlobalConstants.UPCOMING_LEAVES;    
           }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/upcomingLeaves" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String ApproveLeaves(@RequestParam(required=false , defaultValue="")String action,@RequestParam(required=false,defaultValue="")String Cancel,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model){

            try{

            //  System.out.println(loginForm1.getEmployee_id()+"**************************************");
                int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("emp_id"));

                System.out.println(request.getParameter("emp_id")+"**************************************");
                AdminLoginForm loginForm=(AdminLoginForm)model.get("loginForm");
                if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("Confirm")) {

                    System.out.println("I am not coming here");
                    boolean status=LeaveStatusWorker.Approve(id);
                    if (status) {                   
                return GlobalConstants.UPCOMING_LEAVES;
            }
        }
```

The jsp page contains the table where each row has two buttons,
1.Confirm
2.Cancel
On clicking this buttons appropriate action should haapen. If I want to pass some data from a particular row to the controller, how should I get it done? Please help me with this.

```
<form:form method="POST" action="upcomingLeaves.do" commandName="loginForm" modelAttribute="loginForm">
    <table>

            <!-- using Following Statement Take an Record from Leave Table that table present Employee Resent Applied Leave -->
     <%

        CommonDTOBean dtoBean=(CommonDTOBean)session.getAttribute("dtoBean");

        List upcomingLeavesList=(ArrayList)session.getAttribute("upcomingLeavesList");
    %>

            <tr><th style="padding:0 12px 0 12px;">Emp ID </th><th style="padding:0 12px 0 12px;">No. Of Days</th><th style="padding:0 12px 0 12px;">from Date</th>
            <th style="padding:0 12px 0 12px;">To Date</th><th style="padding:0 12px 0 12px;">Leaves Type</th>
            <th style="padding:0 12px 0 12px;">Leaves Period</th><th style="padding:0 12px 0 12px;">Available Leaves</th><th style="padding:0 12px 0 12px;">Status</th></tr>

            <%
        if(upcomingLeavesList!=null){
        for(int i=0;i<upcomingLeavesList.size();i++){

            dtoBean=(CommonDTOBean)upcomingLeavesList.get(i);%>


            <tr><td ><%=dtoBean.getEmployee_id() %></td><td ><%=dtoBean.getAppliedLeave()%></td>
            <td ><%=dtoBean.getFromDate()%></td><td><%=dtoBean.getToDate()%></td><td ><%=dtoBean.getLeaveType()%></td><td><%=dtoBean.getLeavePeriod()%></td><td ><%=dtoBean.getNo_of_leave()%></td><td ></td>
            <td ><%=dtoBean.getLeaveStatus()%></td><td><input type="submit" id="btn" name="Confirm" value="Confirm"/></td><td><input type="submit" id="btn" name="Cancel" value="Cancel"/></td></tr>
            <tr></tr>

            <tr><td><%}}%></td></tr>

        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give your buttons names you can tell which one was clicked because the one clicked and only the one clicked will be passed like a parameter:

```
<input type='submit' name='button1' value='whatever' />
<input type='submit' name='button2' value='whatever' />
```

In the servlet:

```
String button1 = request.getParameter("button1");
String button2 = request.getParameter("button2");
if(button1!=null)
{
   //button1 was clicked
}
else if(button2!=null)
{
   //button2 was clicked
}
```

Comment: ,If I want to transfer the value (100)to controller class from button tag then the values(100) is displaying on the button on view page,how to solve this.